# Access static variable from different files

Tags: ios, objective-c

This should be simple but I am scratching my head on this. I have declared a static variable on the app delegate header file. Something similar to,

```
static NSString *baseURL = @"http://www.google.com/";
```

I change the value of the static variable during the method,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

When I observe the variable using the breakpoint in AppDelegate file , I can see that the value is changed. However when I access the static variable from a different file aka a ViewController I get the old value . Why is this ?

Is there any way I can get the new value ?

Comment: Because it is the intended behavior of a static variable with file scope that it is local to the translation unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo should not use static if you are going to change values.

To get access to "global" strings you need to use *extern*:

```
appDelegate.h

extern NSString *externString;


appDelegate.m

NSString *externString = @"some value";
```

Also you can change the value anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to

1. Declare an `NSString` property in your `AppDelegate.h` file
2. Synthesize in `AppDelegate.m`
3. Inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` set your variables value
4. To access the value use this across the app:

`AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.baseURL = @"google.com";`